# Head tracking Target

Tags: animation, bones, constraints, tracking

[image]

Every time i tried to make the head bone follow a target , it never work  , i tried with both Track To and  Damped track and it always end up with the head being snapped , looking away or not reacting at all.

How do i make it work?
Blend file here : https://ufile.io/j0in41yp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the ball origin to geometry

[image]

and set the contraint to the Y axis

[image]

[image]